# Unable to insert data into a remote sql database using flask

Tags: python, sql-server, pypyodbc

I have a code running on server named 'MGSF.xabis.com'. the main function of the code is to insert data to db table. when i give SQL db table of same server it works fine, but when i want to insert data to  SQL DB Table of another server with name "poeh.xabis.com", it is throwing me below error:

> pypyodbc.DatabaseError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.')

So i don know whether it is possible we can insert data into another server while placing the flask app to insert in another server.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
import mysql.connector
import pypyodbc as pyodbc

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    print("Just go inside ")
    return 'Atlast got inside Page'

@app.route('/WritetoFile/<filename>')
def WritetoaFile(filename):
    f = open(filename+".txt", "a")
    f.write("Now the file has more content!")
    f.close()

    # open and read the file after the appending:
    f = open(filename+".txt", "r")

    return  f.read()

@app.route('/insertdataToDBFile/<dbname>')
def writetodbfile(dbname):
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                          'Server=poeh.xabis.com;'
                          'Database=SelfHeal;'
                          'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
                          'PORT=1433;')
     
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO Issue VALUES('Hi;llos','20120618 10:34:09 AM','kl','prod','20120618 10:34:09 AM','yes','yes','20120618 10:34:09 AM','yes','123','poem')
                ''')
    conn.commit()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM SelfHeal.dbo.Issue')
     
    for row in cursor:
        print(row)
    return (str(cursor.rowcount) + " record inserted.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8015, debug=True)
```

the above code is located on **'MGSF.xabis.com'** and this data should be inserted to the MSSQL DB Table present **"poeh.xabis.com" **

MGSF.xabis.com and poeh.xabis.com are two remote windows servers

Comment: Are you sure that SQL Server is listening on port 8016?  The default for SQL Server is 1433, but it can be configured to listen on any port you want.

Comment: I tried using 1433 too , it is still showing me the same error @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Comment: You'll need to discover the port.  Look in the SQL Server ERRORLOG, SQL Server Configuration Manager MMC snap-in or ask a DBA.  And then you'll need to ensure you can connect to the port, and there are no firewalls configured.

Comment: Okay i will check now @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Comment: checked it is connected to 1433 @DavidBrowne-Microsoft , but i already tried with that PORT number .

Comment: Is there any other way , or any mistake in my code @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Comment: Put your connection string on one line.  It looks like you're missing a `;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228585/discussion-between-niranjana-neeranj-and-david-browne-microsoft).